# tensorflow 'module' object has no attribute 'prepare_attention'

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, sequence, recurrent-neural-network

I am using tensorflow version 1.3. But the tutorial that I following is written on the version 1.0 and I am quite new on tensorflow. The problem that I get is:

> module' object has no attribute 'prepare_attention

And the code is ;

```
tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention(attention_states, attention_option = "bahdanau", num_units = decoder_cell.output_size)
```

I couldn't figure out what the use instead of `tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention()` function. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: You should use https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt which is up-to-date.

Comment: If you mean `tensorflow-seq2seq-tutorials`, that particular tutorial is [deprecated](https://github.com/ematvey/tensorflow-seq2seq-tutorials/issues/24). You can either switch to the latest NMT model or adapt to legacy API, like here - https://github.com/maxim5/tensorflow-seq2seq-translate

Answer (score 0):

Degrade your tensorflow and it'll work. The problem is that prepare_attention is deprecated and hence we use an older version of tf to work with it

Answer (score 0):

Okay, all you need to do is create a new environment with python 3.5.4 and then install tensorflow 1.0.0. That's it. Everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention` works only when the TensorFlow version is 1.0, I have version 2.3.1

My solution:

`tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.prepare_attention`